# Permissions to run a python script with PHP exec()

Tags: php, permissions

I'm trying to execute the following commands in PHP:

```
<?php exec("xdg-open file") ?>
<?php exec("python file.py") ?>
```

All files are in `/var/www/html`.

Other simpler commands seem to be working though. For example:

```
<?php exec("touch file.txt") ?>
<?php echo exec("ls") ?>
<?php echo exec("whoami") ?>
```

I just want to be able to run any Python/shell commands using PHP (without the ones needing sudo). Is it a permission issue? If so, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

To execute a file, make sure the file has executable permissions.

```
chmod +x file.py
```

In a server environment, if run by another process, for instance PHP through Apache/nginX, these permissions must be associated to the user running that server process.

For example, let's say your file name is file.py

fily.py's permissions must be set so the owner is the same as the web server and that owner has executable permissions.

with `chown` we can change the owner, lets say our web server runs as the http user and http group:

```
chown http:http file.py

chmod o+x file.py
```

If the process is not the owner, but in the same group:

```
chmod g+x file.py
```

or neither:

```
chmod o+x file.py
```

Comment: I've just tried what you said and it's still not working; maybe I did something wrong. The user used by the server is www-data which is also the owner. I tried playing a song using a python script and nothing happens.

Comment: There could be various things to consider, is PHP running safe mode? for instance.

Comment: There is no output. I put the code written in my first post in a .php file beside the python script and went to localhost/page.php. Nothing happened. I was expecting for my music player to start and play the song I set.